# Split column value and return split values appropriately

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below table (**MYSQL**),

```
CREATE TABLE x_table (name VARCHAR(100), currencyType VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO x_table VALUES ('Rupee', '5X34'), ('Dollar', '3X34$'), ('Yen', '7X57');
```

I want to split currencyType column into two.

1. split currentyType column by `X`
2. return **count** (***count must be an int value - not string***) 
   for Rupee - count is 5, 
   for Dollar - count is 3
3. return **type**
   for Rupee - 34 doesn't contain $, so type will be 'Non-dollar'
   for dollar - 34$ contains $, type would be "dollar'
   for yen - 57 doesn't contain $, type would be "Non-dollar'

Tried

```
 select name, 
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(currencyType, 'X', 1) as count,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(currencyType, 'X', 2) as type   
 from x_table
```

but not sure how to implement it correctly.

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/XeonLe5g)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your query as the following:

```
SELECT 
  name, 
  CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(currencyType, 'X', 1) AS UNSIGNED) AS count,
  CASE 
    WHEN INSTR(SUBSTRING_INDEX(currencyType, 'X', -1), '$') 
    THEN 'dollar' ELSE 'Non-dollar'
  END AS type   
FROM x_table
```

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/SSE6ARop)

`CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(currencyType, 'X', 1) AS UNSIGNED)`: this will cast the left part of the string as positive number.

To start searching the string from right (get the right part of the string), use -1 instead of 1 for the number parameter in the substring_index function

The `INSTR` function check if the string contains '$' or not.